# Azure Devops - Can impediments show up on Sprint Boards / Backlogs as task level children to PBIs?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm currently able to add a child impediment to a PBI and I see the link in the PBI work item - it looks similar to a task

[image]

However, this same impediment does not show up on the Sprint Board or under the PBI in the backlog view when viewing all child tasks.  Is it possible to get these Impediments to show up in this way - at the task level?

Our admins were able to add impediments at the PBI level, but when adding these as a child to a PBI it replaced the PBI on the task board - not what we want.

Answer (score 0):

To see Impediment as a child to PBI on board, you have to add it to the task level:

[image]

The boards do not support tree view on the same level. They always show a last child and hide its parents.